# How to input() after reading stdin in python?

Tags: python, input, io, stdin

This simple code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import socket
import shlex
import subprocess
import sys
import textwrap
import threading

def execute(cmd):
    cmd = cmd.strip()
    if not cmd:
        return
    output = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(cmd), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return output.decode()

class NetCat:
    def __init__(self, args, buffer=None):
        self.args = args
        self.buffer = buffer
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    
    def run(self):
        if self.args.listen:
            self.listen()
        else:
            self.send()

    def send(self):
        self.socket.connect((self.args.target, self.args.port))
        if self.buffer:
            self.socket.send(self.buffer)
            
        try:
            while True:
                recv_len = 1
                response = ''
                while recv_len:
                    data = self.socket.recv(4096)
                    recv_len = len(data)
                    response += data.decode()
                    if recv_len < 4096:
                        break
                if response:
                    print(response)
                    buffer = input('> ') #input does not return after new line or even EOF (ctrl-d)
                    buffer += '\n'
                    self.socket.send(buffer.encode())
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('User terminated.')
            self.socket.close()
            sys.exit()

    def listen(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Net Tool',
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
        epilog=textwrap.dedent(
        '''Examples:
        netcat.py -t 192.168.1.108 -p 5555 -l -c # command shell
        netcat.py -t 192.168.1.108 -p 5555 -l -u=mytest.txt # upload to file
        netcat.py -t 192.168.1.108 -p 5555 -l -e=\"cat /etc/passwd\" # execute command
        echo 'ABC' | ./netcat.py -t 192.168.1.108 -p 135 # echo text to server port 135
        netcat.py -t 192.168.1.108 -p 5555 # connect to server
        '''
        )
    )
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--command', action='store_true', help='command shell')
    parser.add_argument('-e', '--execute', help='execute specified command')
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--listen', action='store_true', help='listen')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', type=int, default=5555, help='specified port')
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--target', default='127.0.0.1', help='specified IP')
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--upload', help='upload file')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.listen:
        buffer = ''
    else:
        buffer = sys.stdin.read() # stdin is used here, but should that change behaviour of subsequence reading - input() ?
    nc = NetCat(args, buffer.encode())
    nc.run()
```

After `input('> ')`, the prompt never returns, neither after newline nor EOF. Is it because of previous `sys.stdin.read()`? Whats going on

The file is triggered

1. without input: `$ python3 test.py -p 9998` or `$ ./test.py -p 9998`. Then it waits after I enter a message, it is send to server and `'> '` prompt appear (for another message). At which point comes situation described above - after typing the new message, after new line or EOF, nothing happens. The `input()` does not return.
2. with some stdin redirection, e.g `$ echo 'ABC' | python3 test.py -p 9998` in which case, the message `ABC` is sent, but `input()` immediately throws `EOFError: EOF when reading a line`. So there is no prompt at all.

Comment: How are you executing this script? Are you passing something into stdin for it to read? And if so, does the thing you are passing include whatever you're trying to `input`?

Comment: As far as my understanding, in case 1, your `stdin.read()` will carry on consuming input until it receives a termination. If you're not sending that, then the `input()` won't be reached. In case 2, you're passing `'ABC'` as the input to stdin, so if you try and read any more from that (e.g. `input()`) you'll get an EOF. Essentially, don't try and use stdin for two different inputs.

Comment: @khelwood `... stdin will carry on consuming until it receives a termination`, but it DID received EOF in the first message (ctrl-d) - before `input()`, it is after that, that is does not accepts another EOF for `input()`